# Setting Asset Tag (Overriding board_asset_tag)

Tags: linux, ipmi, ipmitool

I am trying to set Asset Tag for DELL server(From Machine1 to Machine2). I have tried the following options

1. `ipmitool dcmi set_asset_tag Machine2`

   - This doesnt seem to set the asset tag. When i try to get the asset tag info via ifru command, I get the old asset tag value. But when I use the command `ipmitool dcmi asset_tag` I get the value which is set. So have ruled out this option due to this inconsistency.
2. `ifru -a Machine2`

   - This sets the asset tag and I get the expected value in ifru. The problem is when I restart(cold/warm) the machine, the asset tag is reset to the old one.

   Upon checking, it seems the value from /sys/class/dmi/id/board_asset_tag will be defaulted.

How do I override the value set in board_asset_tag? Or is there any other way to set asset tag. It seems it can be done via RACADM but I want a common solution which can be applicable to servers from all vendors.